# SQL parse list of values to find greater than/ less than/ range

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle SQL DB column holding a comma separated list of values, and as input I have two numbers - I need to find out if at least one of the numbers in the list of values is between the two input numbers.

Example: 
DB column content: `'100, 200, 300, 400, 500'`
input: 10, 100 
Requested output: true (since 100 is between 10 and 110).

input: 10,80. 
Requested output: false.

Is there any way I could do this in straight SQL (no PL/SQL)?

Comment: As Oracle has no built-in support to deal with comma separated values, I guess you will have to use PL/SQL for this. The better choice however would be to properly normalize your data model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE NUMBER_TABLE_TYPE AS TABLE OF NUMBER;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SplitCSV(LIST IN VARCHAR2, Separator IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER_TABLE_TYPE IS
    OutTable NUMBER_TABLE_TYPE := NUMBER_TABLE_TYPE();  
BEGIN
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(LIST, '[^'||Separator||']+', 1, LEVEL) 
    BULK COLLECT INTO OutTable
    FROM dual
    CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(LIST, '[^'||Separator||']+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;

    RETURN OutTable;
END;
```

And then you could use it for example:

```
WITH t AS (SELECT '100, 200, 300, 400, 500' AS val FROM dual)
SELECT distinct 'true'
FROM t
    CROSS JOIN TABLE(SplitCSV(val, ','))
WHERE COLUMN_VALUE BETWEEN 10 and 80;
```

Or do it all in one single SELECT:

```
WITH t AS 
    (SELECT TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR('100, 200, 300, 400, 500', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) AS NUMBERS
    FROM dual
    CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR('100, 200, 300, 400, 500', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)
SELECT case when count(NUMBERS) > 0 then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end 
FROM t
WHERE NUMBERS BETWEEN 10 AND 80;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `XMLTABLE`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/879e4/12)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table yourtable as select '100, 200, 300, 400, 500' nums from dual;
```

**Query 1**:

```
 WITH t(n)
     AS (SELECT TO_NUMBER (column_value)
         FROM   yourtable,
                XMLTABLE(nums)),
     input(min_val, max_val)
     AS (SELECT Min(TO_NUMBER(column_value)),
                Max(TO_NUMBER(column_value))
         FROM   XMLTABLE('10,100' ))
SELECT CASE
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM   t
                      WHERE  t.n BETWEEN i.min_val AND i.max_val) THEN 'TRUE'
         ELSE 'FALSE'
       END is_between
FROM   input i
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/879e4/12/0)**:

```
| IS_BETWEEN |
|------------|
|     TRUE   |
```